# Get the Foreign Key table data along with Requested table data

Tags: sql, dapper

I have two tables where one table Location References(using Foreign Key relation) to another Table. I am Using Dapper i want to Get the Location Details as well for the Given Customer Table. Like the Below[image]

IS that possible using Dapper. Here is My sample table structure

[image]

Comment: with dapper, you write the SQL yourself. Is there any reason your SQL can't include an INNER JOIN?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Most databases have a System Catalog or Database Catalog set of tables and/or views that you can use SQL to query information about tables, columns, views, indexes, constraints, foreign keys, primary keys, etc.. Given Dapper is an ORM tool (I just had to look it up to find out what it is), I don't see why you couldn't use it as a layer to access the Database Catalog objects. However, I think you should approach this from your database documentation first, and Dapper second. Dapper should be able to function as a layer over top of the Database Catalog in the same manner as it does over standard application databases, at least from a read only perspective.